# How to record video and audio from webcam using ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, webcam, video-recording

I want to record video as well as audio from webcam using ffmpeg,

I have used the following codes to know what devices are available:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

And got the result:

```
ffmpeg version N-54082-g96b33dd Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jun 17 2013 02:05:16 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-
amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --
enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
libavutil      52. 37.101 / 52. 37.101
libavcodec     55. 16.100 / 55. 16.100
libavformat    55.  8.103 / 55.  8.103
libavdevice    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
libavfilter     3. 77.101 /  3. 77.101
libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[dshow @ 024eb460] DirectShow video devices
[dshow @ 024eb460]  "Sirius USB2.0 Camera"
[dshow @ 024eb460]  "Vimicro USB Camera (Altair)"
[dshow @ 024eb460] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 024eb460]  "Microphone (Realtek High Defini"
dummy: Immediate exit requested
```

I am using the following codes to get more details about the device:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -list_options true -i video="Vimicro USB Camera (Altair)"
```

And i am getting the following results:

```
ffmpeg version N-54082-g96b33dd Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jun 17 2013 02:05:16 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-
amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --
enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
libavutil      52. 37.101 / 52. 37.101
libavcodec     55. 16.100 / 55. 16.100
libavformat    55.  8.103 / 55.  8.103
libavdevice    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
libavfilter     3. 77.101 /  3. 77.101
libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[dshow @ 0249b3e0] DirectShow video device options
[dshow @ 0249b3e0]  Pin "Capture"
[dshow @ 0249b3e0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=640x480 fps=30 max   s=640x480 fp
s=30
[dshow @ 0249b3e0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=640x480 fps=30 max s=640x480 fp
s=30
[dshow @ 0249b3e0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=352x288 fps=30 max s=352x288 fp
s=30
[dshow @ 0249b3e0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=352x288 fps=30 max s=352x288 fp
s=30
[dshow @ 0249b3e0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=320x240 fps=30 max s=320x240 fp
s=30
[dshow @ 0249b3e0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=320x240 fps=30 max s=320x240 fp
s=30
[dshow @ 0249b3e0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=176x144 fps=30 max s=176x144 fp
s=30
[dshow @ 0249b3e0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=176x144 fps=30 max s=176x144 fp
s=30
[dshow @ 0249b3e0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=160x120 fps=30 max s=160x120 fp
s=30
[dshow @ 0249b3e0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=160x120 fps=30 max s=160x120 fp
s=30
video=Vimicro USB Camera (Altair): Immediate exit requested
```

When i am trying following codes to get video and audio stream:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -s 320x240 -r 30 -vcodec mjpeg -i video="Vimicro USB Camera (Altair)" e:\output.mp4
```

I am getting an error message as "**Could not set video options
video=Vimicro USB Camera (Altair): Input/output error**"

Following are the error details:

```
ffmpeg version N-54082-g96b33dd Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jun 17 2013 02:05:16 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-
amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --
enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
libavutil      52. 37.101 / 52. 37.101
libavcodec     55. 16.100 / 55. 16.100
libavformat    55.  8.103 / 55.  8.103
libavdevice    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
libavfilter     3. 77.101 /  3. 77.101
libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[dshow @ 002f78e0] Could not set video options
video=Vimicro USB Camera (Altair): Input/output error
```

And i am unable to find where i am doing wrong.

So if anybody can find where i am doing wrong or how to record video as well as audio from webcam using ffmpeg please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What does this say: `ffmpeg -f dshow -list_options 1 -i video="Vimicro USB Camera (Altair)" -f null -`?

Comment: Hi @Mulvya, thanks for your comment i have edited my question, so please read again you will get your answer.

Comment: Skip the `vcodec`, Replace `-s` with `-video_size`, `-r` with `-framerate` and add `-pixel_format yuyv422`

Comment: Hi @Mulvya, after modifying the commands as per your information as follows `ffmpeg -f dshow -video_size 320x240 -framerate 30 -pixel_format yuyv422 -i video="Vimicro USB Camera (Altair)" e:\output.mp4` also i am getting an error **[dshow @ 003179c0] Could not run filter
video=Vimicro USB Camera (Altair): Input/output error**

Comment: Your ffmpeg is very old. Get a recent build.

Comment: Thanks @Mulvya for your replay, latest ffmpeg build working fine but only problem is that the quality of the video is not so good so is there any command to improve the quality of the video.

Comment: Run the list options command and chose the highest resolution available.

Comment: The higest of your device is `pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=640x480 fps=30 max   s=640x480 fp
s=30`, so maybe you need change your device
BTW, ffmpeg would use  the first available configuration

Answer (score 0):

Try this command: `ffmpeg -y -f dshow -i video="Vimicro USB Camera (Altair)":audio="Vimicro USB Camera (Altair)" out.mp4`

For more detail please check:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow

PS. FFmpeg has changed a lot, now my version is `5.1.2`